# Coverdell ESA Tax Consequence For Corporate Contribution

Tags: united-states, children, tax-free-savings, coverdell-esa

I have a small business (C corp) and noticed that corporations can contribute to an Coverdell ESA account with no income limit.

Can I create an ESA account for a child and fund it 100% from corporate contributions? (up to the $2K annual limit)

What are the tax consequences of corporate contributions to an ESA? (both for the corporations and for me)